# Can Javascript / AJAX / JQuery detect whether a form was typed in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I am trying to modify a form field's contents and submit the form from the console. Whenever I use Jquery or JS to modify the field and submit, the page only recognises values which were manually typed in.

The code below should cause field 'lastField' to be submitted as 'spoofed entry', but instead the field is submitted as blank.

```
$('submit').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('#lastField').val('spoofed entry');
    $('submit').submit(); //I also tried .click();
});
```

Is there any way to replicate manual keystroke entry into the field? I think something is detecting the method of entry - I also think it's blocking that entry.

Comment: What you actually wanna do ? I did not get you. But yes you can define a global variable and change the value of the variable on each key up. see keyUp method of JQuery and update value. Use that variable on form

Comment: what's `$('submit')`? a class? an id? superman?

Comment: $('submit') is nothing, so the code won't run, you'll send a basic empty form just by clicking, this JS code is useless

Answer (score 0):

try using ids instead, matching the html in your page

```
$('#submit_button').click(function() {
  $('#lastField').val('spoofed entry');
  $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: it seems you need to read the JQuery docs to implement a working solution, or paste your code to be fixed, it's easy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should put your event listener on the form, not the submit button, like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this)    

    //... do your thing

    form.submit();

});
```

also, i've noticed some strange asyncronous behaiour with $().val() so you might want to wrap `$(this).submit()` in a timeout so that it gives the code a chance to actually do everything...

setTimeout(function(){
    form.submit();
}, 50);

So over all:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this)    

    $('#lastField').val('spoofed entry') 

    setTimeout(function(){
       form.submit();
    }, 50);

});
```

Try it without the timeout first though, because that's pretty hacky, but I remember something like that helping me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and tinkering, I found out the form was an ngsubmit form from angular JS. ).trigger('input'); was necessary after setting the value with JS/JQuery.

After adding that, angular detected the form changes.